# How to handle Ether and Token payment in same contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

How do I have a single contract handle receiving payments in Ether in the constructor and receiving/transferring an ERC20 Standard Token in the same contract's methods?

```
constructor = receiving msg.value in Ether
contract method 1 = receiving msg.value as ERC20 Token
contract method 2 = transfer ERC20 Token to address
```

I understand and have implemented the receiving payment in Ether for the constructor, but I am kind of confused as to how to handle the ERC20 Standard Token in two other contract payable methods.

I understand I could keep track of the amounts of the ERC20 Token inside the contract, but I am wondering how to verify on receiving/transferring that it is that type of token?

Do I need to interface with the deployed ERC20 Token contract to hold all the values and process the transactions for this contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, You have an erc-20 standard token deployed, and now in another contract, you want to have functions for receiving/transferring that token.

> contract method 1 = receiving msg.value as ERC20 Token

AFAIK, you can't have any such function. `msg.value` is always the amount of `wei` send along with the transaction. So you can't have tokens as `msg.value`.

However, you can have the amount of token as a function parameter.

> I understand I could keep track of the amounts of the ERC20 Token
>   inside the contract, but I am wondering how to verify on
>   receiving/transferring that it is that type of token?

If you have to support only one specific token transfer, you won't need to verify the type of token. You can have a function like `function tokenTransfer(unit tokenAmount)` . If you want to support multiple erc-20 tokens, you can have another parameter named `contractAddress` as another function parameter.

> Do I need to interface with the deployed ERC20 Token contract to hold
>   all the values and process the transactions for this contract?

Yes, that is the clean approach to do so. I am not sure what your use case is, but the best way to transfer tokens is to call `transfer` function of that specific contract. But in case you want the same function in another contract you should call the `tokenContract` internally when someone calls function of your contract. This will be easier than keeping track of balances in both contracts.

Comment: This was what I was thinking I would have to do. Thanks for verifying!